# Is there any function to include classes in <a> & <li> tags decendent of wp_nav_menu()?

Tags: wordpress

'header_menu', 
                            'menu_class'        =>'navbar-nav' ,
                            'container'         =>'div' , 
                            'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-center',
                            'container_id'      => 'navbarDefault',
                            'depth'             => 2,
                        )
                );
      ?>

Comment: Please use proper format and also describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to create your own menu class here how to do this;

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248369/how-to-create-this-custom-menu-walker

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker/

This way you can edit and create menus according to what you want.

Note: You can add class through the menu in the wordpress panel, but you will need to manually add to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via the 'nav_menu_css_class' filter:

```php
function wpdocs_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
        // Apply specific class: .special-class
    $classes[] = "special-class";
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class' , 'wpdocs_special_nav_class' , 10, 2 );
```

References:

[Add custom CSS classes to wp_nav_menu’s HTML output using WordPress filters](https://devilsworkshop.org/add-custom-classes-wpnavmenu-condition/)

[Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#comment-206)

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Add class to the li element on a menu.
 *
 * @param $classes
 * @param $item
 * @param $args
 *
 * @return array
 */
function add_classes_on_li( $classes, $item, $args ) {
    if( 'primary' === $args->theme_location ) {
        $classes[] = 'nav-item';
    }

    if( 'secondary' === $args->theme_location ) {
        $classes[] = 'nav-item';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_classes_on_li', 1, 3 );

/**
 * Add class to primary menu anchors.
 *
 * @param $atts
 * @param $item
 * @param $args
 * @param $depth
 *
 * @return array
 */
function add_class_to_primary_menu_anchors( $atts, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if( 'primary' === $args->theme_location ) {
        $atts['class'] = 'nav-link';
    }

    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_class_to_primary_menu_anchors', 10, 4 );
```